# HTACCESS Mod rewrite (rewriting from a short url to a long url)

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

iam trying to rewrite a url like  "http://yoururl.com/abcde"

to "http://yoururl.com/yourfile.php?string=abcde".

I've tried this with

```
RewriteRule ^redirect_v2.php?alias=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php/$1
```

But it wont work.

Thanks for your Help!

Kind Regards

Comment: It seems backwards. What do you want to appear in the browser?

Comment: @PanamaJack Yes its Backwards :) Iam using CI and i want to redirect there. The problem is when i use the CI URI Helpers redirect its not absolutly a 301 redirect, but its needed. so i want to redirect in a single html file, but i cant access the given value "abcde"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically if you want to use a URL like this in the browser.

```
 http://yoururl.com/yourfile.php?string=abcde
```

Then your htaccess will be something like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /yourfile\.php\?string=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?yourfile\.php$ /index.php/%1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: as my comment above, i want it backwards :) not the nice, seo friendly url :)

Comment: Ok so that is this part `http://yoururl.com/abcde`? You want to rewrite it to `index.php/$1`

Comment: maybe yes i want to rewrite it to file.php?getVariable=abcde

Comment: I think I'm still confused, but maybe this is what you want. Try my updated rule.

Comment: Its working, i think :) Iam confused too. I dont want that. Customers are crazy ... Thanks alot mate!